# Delete Object from CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, delete-row, uialertcontroller

I want to Delete an Object from CoreData in an Alert but it´s comes this error. All that i have found was the Function from the TableView to Delete it with Swipe but i want it in an Alert. Thanks for Help.

```
Cannot call value of non-function type `Set<NSManagedObjekt>`
```

Whats does this error mean ? I make that as!NSManagedObject in the code

Here wos the Code from the Alert to delete an Object:

```
DeleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            let indexPath = self.BookTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow


            mgdContext.deletedObjects(book[indexPath!.row] as! NSManagedObject)

            do {
                try self.mgdContext.save()
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }

       }))
```

Comment: I think the error is saying that 'deletedObjects' isn't a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deletedObjects` is a property on `NSManagedObjectContext` that returns a `Set<NSManagedObject>`. Im not really sure how your code compiles passing in an argument, but suffice it to say you should be using `func deleteObject(_ object: NSManagedObject)`

Answer (score 3):

It's just a typo: `deleteObject(`, (without `d` and without `s`),
probably happened due to misleading code completion.